# Javascript does not find Applet in IE9

Tags: java, javascript, html, internet-explorer, applet

i have got a Problem with Javascript and it´s Communication to an applet.
In every Browser Javascript does find the applet and i can call it´s methods, but in IE9 it does not find the object/applet. heres the code

```
<div class="speichern" align="center">
  <object type="application/x-java-applet" width="10" height="10" id="jsap" name="jsap">
    <param name="archive" value="ABD_Downloadmanager.jar,ojdbc6.jar"> </param>
    <param name="code" value="Speichern_Applet.class"> </param>
    <param name="mayscript" value="yes">
    <param name="scriptable" value="true">
  </object>
</div>
```

and the Javascript call :

```
var appletObj = document.getElementsByName('jsap')[0];
var path = appletObj.test();
```

the test Method does just return a String `return "C:/";`

when i use the an `alert(appletObj );`

Firefox does show me `object HtmlObjectElement`

But the IE does only show `object`

i have tried this ways to get the applet without any success:

```
var appletObj = document.getElementsByID('jsap')[0]; 
var appletObj = document.getElementsByID('jsap'); 
var appletObj = document.jsap; 
var appletObj = document.applets[0];
```

for me it looks like the IE simply cannot work with the object tag or something like this? someone got a solution for this or an idea why the IE can not find the object/applet?

Thanks for reading so far

Comment: `<param name="code" value="Speichern_Applet.class"> </param>
    <param name="mayscript" value="yes">`  'To close or not to close.  Only one answers the question.'  Check which one with a [validation service](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: `ojdbc6.jar`  That is ominous.  The applet should likely be doing DB access via a web service.

Answer (score 0):

I Just found out the Problem which came up in here.
I was using the style='visible:hidden' attribute. But a hidden DOM object, in this case the Object tag/ applet won´t be loaded by the IE. I just had to set the size to (0,0). Genius...